# devise: sign up with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I create a `username` column in database. now I want remove `email` and then user `sign up` just by `username`. For this, I can create `username` field in `sign up` page, but again I have to complete email field that server create new user, if else, I get validation error of email field. **How can I remove email validation and replace it with personal validation of username?** and then user just can sign up with enter `username` and `password`?
I have below code to:

`users_controller.rb`:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
  end
```

`views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :username %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "user/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: A couple of questions for you. Since you are removing email field completely so how will you send confirmation instructions to a user? How will you send password reset instructions to user?

Comment: User cannot create account by self, Superadmin create new user by username and if user forget the password, superadmin can reset password. I get user phone number and send password reset to their number.

Comment: I don't think devise will let you remove email all together as it requires it for other purposes. From what you told me i think it'll be better if you create your own simple authentication system rather than trying to customize devise or some other gem

Answer (score 4):

If you check the documentation you have a section explaining how to do it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

Personally I wouldn't remove the email from user settings and stick with the suggested on documentation to create a virtual attribute called login.

If you want to remove completely the email, you'll need to remove it with a migration in order to remove the field from the database table and remove it from the model validation.
Also you need to update your views or partials by replacing email with username. Beware you need to update authentication_keys like it's mentioned on docs (use username instead of login)

Comment: I don't want permit to user to sign up with email and user have to sign up with username with personal validation. I want just replace `email` with `username` and overwrite devise manager to check usernmae validation and remove email validation. By this documentation, I have to get the user email address.

Comment: @mgh I've updated the answer with some directions you can follow.

Comment: umm I did everything but it does not work. I don't see where is the connection between the virtual attribute "login" and anything else. It just says invalid email